# Objective C Protocol Delegate test

Tags: objective-c, xcode, delegates, protocols

I'm studing protocol and delegates using an Example! When I try to re create this example I notice that this condition is not respected:

if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(amountEntered:)]) {blabla}

where is the mistake? Scripts:

First View .h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import "EnterAmountViewController.h"

 @interface DelegateExampleViewController : UIViewController  <EnterAmountDelegate>{

 IBOutlet UILabel *amountLabel;
 }

 -(IBAction)changeAmountPressed;

 @end
```

First View .m

```
#import "DelegateExampleViewController.h"

@implementation DelegateExampleViewController

-(IBAction)changeAmountPressed
{
EnterAmountViewController * enterAmountVC = [[EnterAmountViewController alloc]init];

enterAmountVC.delegate = self;

} 


-(void)amountEntered:(NSInteger)amount
{
amountLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i" , amount];
}

@end
```

Second View .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol EnterAmountDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)amountEntered:(NSInteger)amount;

@end


@interface EnterAmountViewController : UIViewController {

 IBOutlet UITextField *amountTextField;

 id<EnterAmountDelegate> delegate;

 }


-(IBAction)savePressed;

@property(nonatomic,retain) id<EnterAmountDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

Second View .m

```
#import "EnterAmountViewController.h"
#import "DelegateExampleViewController.h"

@implementation EnterAmountViewController

@synthesize delegate;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

amountTextField.text = @"";
[amountTextField becomeFirstResponder];

}


-(IBAction)savePressed
{

if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(amountEntered:)])
{

    [delegate amountEntered:[amountTextField.text intValue]];
    NSLog(@"rugg");
}

}

@end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In the method:

```
-(IBAction)changeAmountPressed
{
  EnterAmountViewController * enterAmountVC = [[EnterAmountViewController alloc]init];

  enterAmountVC.delegate = self;
}
```

you are creating an instance of `EnterAmountViewController` on the stack as a local variable. This variable will be inaccessible at the end of the scope. So, when you execute `savePressed` you are doing it on a different object where you did not set `delegate`.

In other words, when you check

```
if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(amountEntered:)])
```

it returns NO because `delegate` is nil...

The correct way to set the delegate is using the `prepareForSegue` mechanism:

```
@implementation DelegateExampleViewController

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

   [(EnterAmountViewController*)segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self];
}
...
```

You do not need the `changeAmountPressed` method nor the relative binding.

Comment: In firstView .m I'm declaring enterAmountVC.delegate = self; Is it not sufficient?

Comment: sorry I can't understand! Can you modify the piece of script and past here so I can study it? Please

Comment: it is not code: you should connect your view controllers in Interface Builder... I cannot paste that... or are you not using Interface Builder?

Comment: yeah, that's the same. identify the object that represents your `EnterAmountViewController`; then show the bindings pane; you will see there a `delegate` item; click on the small rounded circle next to it and drag onto the other object representing your `DelegateExampleViewController` and you are done.

Comment: I found delegate in the connection pane but I can't link it with object of another class! This is my project https://rbpjjq.bay.livefilestore.com/y1pDDU5PBCrVSYVOizZE0zsxZvxhijFwfhUEnBFm80FP6aemcRtdARBc2u5YSJoNoxpPXBAyt8r6QU4JacWsJ7LqTmxOM5aie6a/bibi.zip?download&psid=1   Sorry

Comment: I can´t access the project; it asks for authentication.

Comment: I tried to sign up for that service so to be able to download; I tried with 2 different mail addresses, but I have not received the confirmation mail yet; I suspect there are some problems... could you just email me a zip? if you go to my profile, you will find my web site address, and there my contact info...

Comment: please, see my edit. I had not realized you were using the StoryBoard and 2 separate xibs. In that case, the way to go is `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: it wooooork :) Thank you very much!!

Comment: +1 for patience, and because it looks like the OP isn't going to upvote or accept any time soon.